# moving of disc in tower of hanoi

Tags: c, recursion

Please explain to me the recursion process step by step using F7.

I just can't correlate the return with flow of control.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void t_of_h(char, char, char, int);

void main()
{
    int n;
    clrscr();

    printf("Enter no of DISC in Tower of Hanoi : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("\nTower of Hanoi using %d DISCS\n",n);

    t_of_h('X', 'Y', 'Z', n);
    getch();
}

void t_of_h(char p1, char p2, char p3, int n)
{
   if(n==0)
     printf("Unsuccessful move\n");
   if(n==1)
     printf("Move DISC from %c to %c\n",p1,p3);
   else
   {
      t_of_h(p1,p3,p2,n-1);
      t_of_h(p1,p2,p3,1);
      t_of_h(p2,p1,p3,n-1);
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that 'void main()' is wrong - `int main()` is OK though `int main(void)` is arguably better, and you should return 0 on success.  Also, the `<conio.h>` header is very Windows-specific, as is the use of `clrscr()` and `getch()` - they are not ISO Standard C functions and headers.

Comment: if i m using int main(), i m facing conflict with using getch() and return statement. a warning message is coming : unreachable code

Comment: @alfesani: well, getch() should be declared in `<conio.h>`; you need to add 'return 0;' at the end of `main()` when it is declared to return `int`.  Unreachable code?  That is very odd...  I omitted the 'clrscr()', 'getch()' and the header when I test compiled on MacOS X.  The code was clean with the obvious fixes, under GCC 4.5.1 with options `gcc -O -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition hanoi.c -o hanoi`.

Comment: sorry sir ,i dont mean to say that u r wrong. i use windows xp and turbo c compiler . i m a student of 2nd yr bca. i dont have any knowledge of industrially used compilers. what my compiler gave the output i just posted it. and if u did minded it , i m really sorry

Comment: @alfesani: I'm not fussed - I don't have a Windows machine on hand, so I can't reproduce your problem.  I'm not sure that it shouldn't be counted as a 'cruel and unusual punishment' making people learn computing on Windows - especially C programming.  It also means I can't tell why you see the errors you see.

Answer (score 3):

How do you move N disks from tower A to tower B?

1. Move N-1 disks from tower A to tower C.
2. Move the bottom disk from tower A to tower B.
3. Move N-1 disks from tower C to tower B.

The code is a pretty direct implementation of that.  If you assume that you can move an arbitrary number of disks from one tower to another, then this clearly works.  How do you move N-1 disks from tower A to tower C?  Well, you move N-2 disks from tower A to tower B, then move the N-1th disk from tower A to tower C, then move the N-2 disks form tower B to tower C.  And repeat...

Eventually, the recursion stops because you have a single disk to move.

An interesting exercise is "write a test harness that ensures that no invalid moves are ever made".

---

OK - I've run the code.  Its visualization of the process is gruesome.  It is very hard to see what is going on.  But it is a direct report of what the algorithm does.  Now what?

#### 1 disk

```
Enter no of DISC in Tower of Hanoi : 1

Tower of Hanoi using 1 DISCS
Move DISC from X to Z
```

#### 2 disks

```
Enter no of DISC in Tower of Hanoi : 2

Tower of Hanoi using 2 DISCS
Move DISC from X to Y
Move DISC from X to Z
Move DISC from Y to Z
```

Note that it is moving disks from X to Z.  How do you move 2 disks from X to Z?  Move the top disk from X to Y.  Move the bottom disk from X to Z.  Move the original top disk from Y to Z.

#### 3 disks

```
Enter no of DISC in Tower of Hanoi : 3

Tower of Hanoi using 3 DISCS
Move DISC from X to Z
Move DISC from X to Y
Move DISC from Z to Y
Move DISC from X to Z
Move DISC from Y to X
Move DISC from Y to Z
Move DISC from X to Z
```

Comment: @gameover: when I taught recursion using Tower of Hanoi as the example (because it is better by far than recursion for Fibonacci numbers or factorials, which are the two most popular alternatives), I told people to write a function that would implement the algorithm, and to call a function 'movedisc()' which would take two arguments, the source tower and the target tower. I provided the movedisc() function to ensure that the moves were all valid. It diagnoses attempts to put a big disk on top of a small disk, or non-existent poles, or an attempt to move a disk that wasn't there. [...cont'd...]

Comment: @gameover: My test harness also provided code to display the towers at each step, and dealt with command line arguments and other stuff like that too.  It actually uses the Unix-ish curses library to do the display - so it overwrites the same space on the screen continually, rather than racking up lots of pages of output.

Answer (score 0):

Using F7?

Well if you are having trouble understanding the recursion, get out a pen and paper and step through the program. Stack each call with the correct arguments.

It should be simpler when you can visualise it.

Comment: thanx  bt i m facincg problems in visualising it